# RCD in hybrid solar systems

Tags: inverter, solar-charge-controller, rcd

Considering a hybrid solar systems that consists of:

- a hybrid inverter/charger that is also connected to the power grid
- batteries
- pv panels
- load.

[image]

I would like to ask about RCDs.
First of we should add a RCD device between the Inverter/Charger and the load. Probably a 30mA Type B. In this way even when the grid fails, the protection will still exist.

However should we put another RCD between the AC grid and the Inverter/Charger? If an internal fault occurs inside the inverter, the RCD between the Inverter/Charger and the load will trip?
A possible solution could be to put a 300mA Type B between the AC Grid and the Inverter/Charger. Are there any standards that we need to follow?